Example of a complex function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ differentiable only at $z_1=1+i\,, z_2=1-i\,, z_3=-1+i\,, z_4= -1-i$
I'm taking a first course in complex analysis and in the last assignment we were asked the following question:

Give an example for a complex valued function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is differentiable only for these 4 complex numbers: $$ z_1=1+i\,, z_2=1-i\,, z_3=-1+i\,, z_4= -1-i$$

In the lecture, we saw 2 important results that I tried to use for this construction:\

$\,$we saw that a every complex function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ can be expressed as $f=u+iv\,$ for $\,u,v:\mathbb{R}^2:\to\mathbb{R}$.\
and more importantly that a $f$ is differentiable (in the "complex sense") at $\,\,z_0=x_0+iy_0\,\,$ if and only if $u,v$ are differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations i.e $$(1)\,\,u_x=v_y$$ $$(2)\,\,u_y=-v_x $$

Thanks for the help!

What does the statement "$z=\pm1\pm i \iff (\pm1,\pm i)$" mean?

did you try constructing two functions $u,v:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that are differentiable everywhere but only satisfy the C-R equations at the prescribed points?

i meant to say in these 4 points on the complex plain:
(1,i), (-1,i), (-1,i), (-1-,i)

None of the points $(1,i)$, $(-1,i)$, $(-1,i)$ and $(-1,-i)$ belong to the complex plane.

I meant in these 4 complex numbers
1+i
1-i
-1+i
-1-i

Line 4 : Poor four "complexed" numbers. :)

This is easy to do using the Wirtinger derivatives. Let$$\varphi(z)=(z-1-i)(z-1+i)(z+1-i)(z+1+i)=z^4+4.$$Then you are after a function $f$ such that $\frac\partial{\partial\overline z}f(z)=\varphi(z)$. That's easy; just take$$f(z)=z^4\overline z+4\overline z=z^3|z|^2+4\overline z.$$Then $f$ is complex-differentiable exactly at those points at which $\frac\partial{\partial\overline z}f(z)$ vanishes, which are $1+i$, $1-i$, $-1+i$, and $-1-i$.

can you maybe motivate this choice? (it just doesn't seems like anything i would even consider doing). if you have some tips on how to think of these type of questions that would be much appreciated as well. thank you

I used that fact that the zeros of $\varphi$ are the four complex numbers that you are interested in, together with the fact that $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0$ if and only if $\frac\partial{\partial\overline z}f(z_0)=0$.

These $4$ points in $\mathbb R^2$ are characterized by an equation such as
$$(x^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2=0.$$
If we set $u(x,y)=f(x)$ and $v(x,y)=g(y)$ then we already have $u_y=-v_x=0$ everywhere. Now choose a real polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=(x^2-1)^2$ and a real polynomial $g(y)$ such that $g'(y)=-(y^2-1)^2,$ then the equation $u_x=v_y$ is precisely the condition that characterizes our $4$ points.
